# AS3 How to remove object from array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a array called 'BODY_STAT_ARRAY' and in this array it holds a object called 'body_stat'. This array needs to increase a decrease in size all the time, how do i remove the last object from the array, here is a example which doesn't work

if(BODY_STAT_ARRAY.length > target_size)
{
BODY_STAT_ARRAY.slice(BODY_STAT_ARRAY.indexOf(BODY_STAT_ARRAY[BODY_STAT_ARRAY.length-1]),1)
// this line above should remove the last object in the array 
}

So where am I going wrong, how do you make it work.

If you can help, I would love to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to remove the last object from an array is to call `pop`:

`BODY_STAT_ARRAY.pop();`

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, that very easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Slice will not modify the Original Array . It will give an another Array with the defined range .

Only Splice will modify the original Array , so as to remove or add elements .

```
var a:Array = [1,2,3,4];

a.slice(1,1);
trace(a);           // Output is : 1,2,3,4

a.splice(1,1);
trace(a);           //  Output is : 1,3,4
```